# How to copy data from one column to another?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, sql-null

I am trying to add Property Address in columns that have a missing value.

I use the below to identify common parcel IDs with corresponding property address since the same parcelIDs have the same PropertyAddress as well.

```
select n.UniqueID, n.ParcelID, n.PropertyAddress, n2.UniqueID, n2.ParcelID, n2.PropertyAddress, IFNULL(n.PropertyAddress,n2.PropertyAddress) 
from Nashnew n 
join Nashnew n2 
on n.ParcelID = n2.ParcelID 
where n2.PropertyAddress =''
and n.UniqueID != n2.UniqueID
```

I get this result:
[image]

Now I want to add the data in column IFNULL(n.PropertyAddress,n2.PropertyAddress) to the missing PropertyAddress cells using the below:

```
UPDATE Nashnew 
set propertyAddress = IFNULL(n.PropertyAddress,n2.PropertyAddress)
from Nashnew n 
join Nashnew n2 
on n.ParcelID = n2.ParcelID 
and n.UniqueID != n2.UniqueID 
where n2.PropertyAddress =''
```

However, I get this result, where all the PropertyAddress are the same for all rows.
[image]

How do I add the correct PropertyAddress to the

Comment: In your join on the 2nd query, why are you joining on Unique ID not equal to Unique ID?

Comment: Otherwise, when I join the tables there will be duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code in the `UPDATE` statement you are actually joining twice the table `Nashnew`.
Also you should check if the column `PropertyAddress` of the updated copy of `Nashnew` is `null` or empty:

Change to this:

```
UPDATE Nashnew AS n
SET propertyAddress = n2.PropertyAddress
FROM Nashnew AS n2 
WHERE n.ParcelID = n2.ParcelID 
  AND n.UniqueID <> n2.UniqueID 
  AND COALESCE(n.PropertyAddress, '') = ''
  AND COALESCE(n2.PropertyAddress, '') <> '';
```